# NPE at android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have this NPE when I call getText() on EditText.
I have an alert and I set my layout as a view to an alert and I need to get the text from EditText.
Thank you for any help

**Here is my code**

```java
        LinearLayout view;
        EditText input;
        Button in;
        Button gfxtr;
        Button gfh;

        private void numItem(int position) {
            view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
            in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.in);
            gfxtr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gfxtr);
            gfh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gfh);

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Введите новое количество");

            alert.setView(view);



            alert.setPositiveButton("ДА", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String qq = input.getText().toString();


                }
            });


            alert.setNegativeButton("НЕТ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
```

**XML:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/in"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="in"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:text="шт"></Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gfxtr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="gfxtr"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:text="пачек"></Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gfh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="gfh"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:text="пар"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call findViewById on view. Try it like this:

```
input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input);
```